# The Scrollbar Comes Out When I Write a Long Article (CKEditor)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ckeditor

Even if I don't use CKEditor or use CKEditor, I'm having a problem like below: the scrollbar comes out and the article is going sideways.

[Scroolbar Image. Please click to see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxMwd.png)

And this is my code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p>
            <%#Eval("longdescription") %>
        </p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the image you the content in the first line is continuous. That is the reason for the  scrollbar.

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,.</p>
<p>gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks sir. I didn't know that.